# Mitigating - Microsoft XML Parser (MSXML) and XML Core Services Unsupported (62758)

Tags: xml

We have a number of host that are running an outdated and now unsupported version of MS XML Parser\Core Services. I am trying to find a way to mitigate this issue silently on workstations, hopefully without breaking anything. I have been searching for some method via power-shell perhaps that I can use to verify the XML version running and upgrade unsupported versions. I have not been able to find anything specifically related to XML. I would appreciate any info or bread crumbs you can provide.